# How can I search all packages with hoogle via command line?

Tags: haskell, hoogle

I've installed hoogle locally and have run `hoogle generate`.

If I run `hoogle maybeToEither` I get:

```
Data.Either.Utils maybeToEither :: MonadError e m => e -> Maybe a -> m a
Either maybeToEither :: Monoid b => (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
Network.Haskoin.Util maybeToEither :: b -> Maybe a -> Either b a
```

However if I use the web search I get a few more entries: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=maybeToEither

Is there a way I can generate the same 'database' locally? Or is there possibly a CLI for searching  https://hoogle.haskell.org?

According to https://wiki.haskell.org/Hoogle I should be able to run `hoogle data` or `hoogle data all` - but this seems do just do a search (so maybe outdated?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried:

```
$ cabal update
$ cabal install hoogle
Installed hoogle-5.0.17.2
$ hoogle generate --download
$ hoogle maybeToEither
```

And got the response:

```
Data.Either.Utils maybeToEither :: MonadError e m => e -> Maybe a -> m a
Data.Either.Extra maybeToEither :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
Extra maybeToEither :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
Protolude.Either maybeToEither :: e -> Maybe a -> Either e a
Agda.Utils.Either maybeToEither :: Maybe a -> Either () a
Intro maybeToEither :: () => a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
```

At the moment the web shows 6 entries, because it has merged the `Data.Either.Extra` and `Extra` entries into one line as they refer to the same definition. Other than that, they match.

Note that `hoogle generate` generates a database based on what you have already downloaded, so if you run `hoogle generate` every month the result will not change. Adding `--download` forces Hoogle to download afresh.

Answer (score 1):

This project might be of interest: https://github.com/andrevdm/bhoogle

I've also written bash function (depends on jq, fzf, xclip):

```
hoogle_searchAndCopy() {
  wget -qO- https://hoogle.haskell.org/\?hoogle\="$1"\&scope\=set%3Astackage\&mode\=json \
    | jq -r ".[] | \"import \\(.module.name)\\n\\(.package.name)\\n--\"" \
    | fzf | xclip ;
  }
```

`hoogle_searchAndCopy maybeToEither` results in:

[image]